# cannot always load the picture on click and hover

Tags: java, image, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

I am making a launcher application, i wish to change the button depending on the action taken, right now i want to change the button when the following actions happen, either the player hovers over the image, clicks on the image, releases the image click or exits the hover. The issue i have is that it doesn't always load correctly, which is odd.

```
package LostStory;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LaunchPanel extends JComponent {

Image image;
JButton play;
SystemTray tray;

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("res/images/buttons/playNonHover.png");
ImageIcon iconHover = new ImageIcon("res/images/buttons/playHover.png");
ImageIcon iconClick = new ImageIcon("res/images/buttons/playClick.png");

public LaunchPanel(Image img) {
    this.image = img;

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    init();

}

public void init() {
    play = new JButton("Play Lost Story", icon);

    play.setBounds(85, 210 - 75, getWidth() - 165, 50);

    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                run.exec("notepad");
                if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                    tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
                    play.setIcon(play.getIcon());
                    // Main.getClient().getJFrame().setVisible(false);
                    // tray.add(img);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    play.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        } // no use

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if (iconHover.getImageLoadStatus() == 8) {
                play.setIcon(iconHover);
                play.setIcon(play.getIcon());
                System.out.println("Entered");
            }
            System.out.println(iconHover.getImageLoadStatus());
        } // use

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (icon.getImageLoadStatus() == 8) {
                play.setIcon(icon);
                play.setIcon(play.getIcon());
                System.out.println("Exited");
            }
            System.out.println(icon.getImageLoadStatus());
        } // use

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (iconClick.getImageLoadStatus() == 8) {
                play.setIcon(iconClick);
                play.setIcon(play.getIcon());
                System.out.println("Pressed");
            }
            System.out.println(iconClick.getImageLoadStatus());

        } // use

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (icon.getImageLoadStatus() == 8) {
                play.setIcon(icon);
                play.setIcon(play.getIcon());
                System.out.println("Released");
            }
            System.out.println(icon.getImageLoadStatus());
        } // use

    });

    add(play);
}

}
```

The first button always loads (because it is the default one) it returned an '8' when i tried using the IconImage.getImageLoadStatus() so i expected that to be '8' if it was succesfully loaded. (This is not the case though, it will always return 8 as far as i know).

So TL;DR: How do i make sure the ImageIcons are always loaded and will apply correctly?

Comment: 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) Once the app. has an URL with path to the image, use `ImageIO` to load it. The image icons will load the image asynchronously, which seems to be the problem here. 3) See ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson woops, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to manipulate the icon using the setIcon() method.

A JButton has methods to set the icon for various states `setRolloverIcon`,     `setPressedIcon`, etc.

Read the API for other properties.

Also, a painting method is for painting only. Never create components from a painting method. Get rid of the `init()` method from your paintComponent() method.

Components should be created and added to the panel in the constructor of the panel.

Comment: How could i otherwise achieve putting in the button? Once i have drawn the background the that comes with it is that the button will not pop up (because it will be behind the drawn image)

Comment: @pandaJuan, The button's don't appear because you are extending `JComponent`. `JComponent` doesn't use a layout manager so your components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. Change your class to extend `JPanel` then you will be using the default `FlowLayout` (you can change this if you wish).